# Pandas/Python ruining JSON data in DataFrames

Tags: python, json, string, pandas

I'm interacting with an API and getting JSON data back.
At the top level of the JSON object I have 'regular' data but some fields have more advanced structures:

```
{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": "string",
    "spam": {
                "egg":"green",
                "ham":"yum",
                "ran": {
                        "out_of":"fake_words"
                       }
            }
}
```

I need to preserve these advanced structures ("spam") as valid JSON

I'm getting the data using Requests and loading this into a Pandas DataFrame like so:

```
api_result = api.get_data().json()     #the json output of the Request object
df = read_json(json.dumps(api_result))
```

This gives me a nice DataFrame with three columns, as I expect (this is also what I want). The problem comes with the strings:

```
foo    bar        spam
1      'string'   {'egg':'green','ham':'yum','ran':{'out_of':'fake_words'}
```

Pandas or Python has changed all the strings in my data to single quotes (') instead of valid JSON double quotes ("). This behaviour ruins all the downstream processing that is expecting valid JSON objects since all the quotes are now single quotes.

*EDIT--> My program writes out a csv that is ingested into a database table expecting valid JSON in many of the fields. This table is used by many other processes for further analysis and data preparation. <--EDIT*

Is there any way to tell Pandas/Python to stop changing my strings from double to single quotes? I know the general concession is that single quotes are more Pythonic but now they're ruining everything for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what's "ruined"?

Comment: @IanS Yes, in the question above, please note the initial data is all wrapped in double quotes. Once the data is put into a DataFrame, all the data now is wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: @jbarney: would it be ok if we serialize the spam part separately and then laod the data to df ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to generate valid JSON in Python, the best route is the built-in `json` package. You can use the `dumps` function to create a valid JSON string from a Python dictionary:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {'egg':'green','ham':'yum','ran':{'out_of':'fake_words'}}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"ham": "yum", "ran": {"out_of": "fake_words"}, "egg": "green"}'
```

---

Edited answer based on edited question:

The problem is that when you read JSON into a Pandas dataframe, it converts *everything* into Python objects. In your case, the JSON strings are being converted into Python dicts, and when you print the results it shows Python's string representation of the dicts. This representation is almost like JSON, but is not JSON.

What you need to do is to convert the dicts in your dataframe to valid JSON strings. To do this conversion in the `"spam"` column, you could use an `apply()` method call, e.g.

```
data['spam'] = data['spam'].apply(json.dumps)
```

Now the column contains JSON strings rather than Python dicts.

Comment: This is what I do to put the data into the Pandas DataFrame, but the moment the new data is IN the DataFrame, all the JSON that was previously valid (with double quotes) is made invalid (with single quotes).

Comment: That's just Python's string representation of the dict in your dataframe. To get the valid json representation, try e.g. ``json.dumps(df['spam'][0])``

Comment: Another way to say it: when you create a dataframe from JSON, pandas parses *all* the JSON and turns it into Python objects. To get valid JSON back from these objects, you can call ``json.dumps(obj)``.

Comment: That works perfectly. Now when I write the data, I have valid JSON. Only problem is that it's got two quotes around each field in the JSON. That's another problem and something i can probably configure in df.to_csv().

Thanks!

I would 'accept' the answer but an error keeps occuring preventing me from doing so. I'll try again later

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd
import json
a = {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": "string",
    "spam": {
                "egg":"green",
                "ham":"yum",
                "ran": {
                        "out_of":"fake_words"
                       }
            }
}
a["spam"] = json.dumps(a["spam"])
df = json_normalize(a)
df
```

[image]